# How to set TZ in TDengine docker image tdengine/tdengine

Tags: docker, tdengine

Currently TZ environment is not recognized by tdengine/tdengine docker image. Is there a solution to the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  taosd:
    image: tdengine/tdengine
    environment:
      - TZ=Asia/Shanghai
    hostname: taosd
    entrypoint: 
      - bash
      - "-c"
      - 'set -e; export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive; apt-get update && apt-get install -y tzdata; echo $$TZ; [ "$$TZ" != "" ] && ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $$TZ > /etc/timezone; taosd'
```